# "article deleting route" - which word order is correct?

Tags: articles, word-order

I want to briefly say that I've added the URL route which deletes the specified article record from the website. I'm hesitant which word order is correct and which articles to use:

1. Added (a|the|) article deleting (a|the|) route.
2. Added (a|the|) deleting article route.
3. Added the route deleting (an|the) article.

Comment: The meaning of your sentence isn't clear. It seems to say "added.... from". Try putting the meaning into two or three separate sentences, and then put your attempts to combine them.

Comment: I hope it works better now.

Comment: So, you're saying that a URL route is deleting something? How can that be? And you said that you've added that URL route to ... to what? It's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A knife for opening a box would be a *box-opening knife*.

A kit for cleaning cars would be a *car-cleaning kit*.

A wall that bears a load is a *load-bearing wall*.

So logically, a route for deleting articles would be an **article-deleting route**.

What you are describing is *purpose*, not an *action*, so this is the only way to use the present participle of a verb in this context. A box-cutting knife isn't constantly cutting boxes, but it is there for *the purpose of cutting*. Likewise, your route won't constantly be deleting articles, but if you want to delete an article, you use that route.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a [commit message](https://xkcd.com/1296/) of some sorts? As the linked comic shows, these are known for brevity ([headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) is common) and not exactly for correct grammar.

Anyway, I guess the following messages would work, and I have a preference for the indefinite article (though it's hard to pinpoint why).

> - Added an/the article deletion route
> - Added a/the "delete article" route
> - Added a/the route for deleting an article

Note the use of 'deletion' in the first case, the quotes in the second (to 'group' them), and the addition of 'for' in the third case.